# Растянуть несколько div в div 100% css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как растянуть дочерние `div` в родительском `div` который имеет `width: 100%;`.
Таблица не подходит.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = $("#glob").width();
var width_child = width / 7-7;
$(".child").width(width_child.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
.time {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.child {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="glob" class="time">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для родительского элемента с классом `.time` задайте свойство `display: flex`, а для дочерних элементов с классами `child` свойство `flex-grow: 1;`

Результат

```css
.time {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="glob" class="time">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А тогда и скрипт не нужен)